# How to merge only new addition in text/json files?

Tags: git, text, merge, git-merge

I want to programmatically merge two files but need it like this

```
file1
{
 "name" : "john",
 "age" : "24"
}

file2
{
 "name" : "john doe",
 "class" : "A",
 "age" : "25"
}

output
{
  "name" "john",
  "age" : "24",
  "class" : "A"
}
```

I used `git-merge file1.txt file1.txt file2.txt` but it's merging the name field also I only need to update new line additions thanks

Is there another way without git for example using PHP or any other language?

Comment: `git-merge` doesn't interpret JSON to guess what you could consider a correct result, it operates text-based. Write code for that, you only need to read merge and write the code again. Maybe you could use `jq` as well, but that's effectively just another (specialized) language you'd have to learn first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php for that with only one command `array_replace_recursive`:

```
<?php
$file1 = '
{
 "name" : "john",
 "age" : "24"
}
';

$file2 = '
{
 "name" : "john doe",
 "class" : "A",
 "age" : "25"
}
';

$output = '
{
  "name" "john",
  "age" : "24",
  "class" : "A"
}
';

$f1 = json_decode($file1, true);
$f2 = json_decode($file2, true);

$out = array_replace_recursive($f2, $f1);

//var_dump($out);
echo json_encode($out, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

output:

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "class": "A",
    "age": "24"
}
```